# Alternative ways to manipulate excel files in aws lambda

Tags: .net, excel, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, google-sheets-api

I have a desktop application which takes data by reading an excel sheet so accordingly that we process some data and write them to a new excel file. 

 So currently we are in process of converting this to a cloud based solution. We are planning to use aws with .net core/nodsjs. I found that handling excels in web servers are pretty hard work. cos either we have to use an COM object or run time somewhere

So what are the solutions that are available options out there to overcome this issue? (Will google spreadsheet will fit in here ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) to read and write excel files.  ClosedXML seems to have good documentation, an active development team, and a large set of features.  Furthermore, ClosedXML is free. I have not found any other free software for reading Excel that works as well or seems as stable for a production environment.  COM is not recommended even by Microsoft because it is slow and has memory leaks.

A client side solution I have also used recently to read data is [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/).  Although not an excel solution, this may be an alternative option. Papa parse is a javascript library that provides client side csv parsing and works smoothly.

Comment: Great info, have to you used this library with .net core development ?

Comment: @CharithW I have not used it specifically with a .NET Application, but I am using it with a WPF application built through Visual Studio

Comment: ClosedXML won't work in lambda, it requires System.Drawing - libdl, which is not available on linux by default - in docker this can be added manually - not sure about Lambda